# R Shiny conditionalPanel odd behavior

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `conditionalPanel` to create a UI that first presents a panel with options to the user and then displays a tabbed dashboard using `tabsetPanel`. The simple act of adding another `tabPabel` as shown below somehow prevents the server.R file from running. I've tested using print statements. It seems like the Shiny app is breaking, but I can't find a syntax error or any reason for it to be.

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "output.panel == 'view.data'",
  tabsetPanel(id = "type",
    tabPanel("Script", value = "script",
      fluidPage(
        br(),
        fluidRow(
          column(3, uiOutput("script.name")),
          column(3, uiOutput("script.message"))
        ),
        hr(),
        plotlyOutput("plotly")
      )
    ),
    tabPanel("Location", value = "location",
      fluidPage(
        br(),
        fluidRow(
          # column(3, uiOutput("id.range"))
        ),
        hr(),
        plotlyOutput("plot")
      )
    )
    # when this tabPanel is uncommented it doesn't work
    # ,tabPanel("Accelerometer", value = "accelerometer",
    #   fluidPage(
    #     br(),
    #     hr(),
    #     plotlyOutput("plot")
    #   )
    # ),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not failing because of the additional `tabPanel`, it's failing because it contains a duplicate reference to `output$plot`. Each output of the `server` function can only be displayed once. For example, this runs, but will fail if the duplicated line is uncommented:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # textOutput('some_text'),
  textOutput('some_text')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$some_text <- renderText('hello world!')
})

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

A simple solution is to save the results of the `render*` function to a local variable, which you can then save to two outputs:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  textOutput('some_text'),
  textOutput('some_text2')
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  the_text <- renderText('hello world!')
  output$some_text <- the_text
  output$some_text2 <- the_text
})

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```